# Physical or Virtual address identification

Tags: debugging, operating-system, gdb, reverse-engineering, memory-address

I am having hard time in figuring out between Physical and Virtual address. I have a binary which I am loading in IDA disassembler which shows me address such as `0x000008a1` . When I debug the same binary in gdb it shows me address as `0x5555555508a1` .

When I do `info proc mappings` in `gdb` it gives me an unusual address in libc `0x7ffff7a0d000` which starts with 0x7ff....

So, I want to know

1.) Why does gdb appends `0x0x55555555` before the correct address which IDA shows

2.) What are those addresses ? Virtual or Physical ?

3.) Why is the libc address starts with `0x7ffff7a` ?

4.) How do I figure out Physical address of a running process ?

Answer (score 0):

> IDA disassembler which shows me address such as 0x000008a1 . When I debug the same binary in gdb it shows me address as 0x5555555508a1 .

You have a [position-independent executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Position-independent_executables) (recently this is default on many distributions). The binary is relocated to address `0x555555550000`.

By default, GDB disables address randomization, so you will always get consistent relocated address. You can re-enable randomization under GDB with `set disable-randomization off`, and then the binary will be relocated to different addresses from run to run.

> When I do info proc mappings in gdb it gives me an unusual address in libc 0x7ffff7a0d000

There is *nothing* unusual about that address.

> What are those addresses ? Virtual or Physical ?

They are virtual addresses: you *never* see physical addresses in user-space programs, only the kernel deals with them.

Comment: So what is the `0x7ffff7a0d000` address for ? libc address ?

Comment: @Adshead Yes. What do you find surprising about it?